# Why Facebook Pixel Helper found two pixels on page - PageView and fb_page_view?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-pixel

I got website with facebook login, anatitycs and also I added basic facebook pixel.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuxOu.png "Facbook App snip"

Suddenly I noticed that the Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome extension shows that there are 2 pixels found on the site. All the time there was only one (**PageView**)

Where did the other (**fb_page_view**) come from?

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCbMY.png "Facebook Pixel Helper snip"

I looked at the results of both and each of them shows different statistics

Facebook Pixel code in my page:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
        <script>
            !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
                if (f.fbq) return;
                n = f.fbq = function () {
                    n.callMethod ?
                        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
                };
                if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
                n.push = n;
                n.loaded = !0;
                n.version = '2.0';
                n.queue = [];
                t = b.createElement(e);
                t.async = !0;
                t.src = v;
                s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
            }(window, document, 'script',
                'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', '7095...'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
            fbq('track', 'PageView');
                    </script>
        <noscript>
            <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
                 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=7095...&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
        </noscript>
        <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Why Chrome FB Pixel Helpers shows two different pixels?
I'm expecting only one pixel - PageView, that I added (code above)

Comment: Does the id of the second pixel match your app id? Do you have the normal JS SDK embedded as well on that page, initialized with that app id?

Comment: Yes, the ID of the second pixel match my app ID

Comment: What you mean with "normal embedded"? Here is screenshot of how I embedded JS SDK - [link](https://imgur.com/y7RqpLR) And Yes, I also use facebook customer chat

Comment: You got autoLogAppEvents set to true there, and AFAIK that causes it to use its own “pixel”.

Comment: Thank you. I set **autoLogAppEvents** to **false** and it solved the problem. The second pixel is no longer appears.

Comment: @04FS please provide your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had `autoLogAppEvents` set to true in your initialization of the Customer Chat SDK (which itself is just an extension of the “standard” JS SDK), and that causes it to do its own tracking, using the app id as pixel id.